# Programmatically update meta box checkboxes created by another plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a WordPress plugin that needs to integrate with another plugin named **WordPress Hide Posts** when my plugin creates the posts using wp_insert_post. Is there a way I programmatically update checkboxes?

I usually used this to update my meta but here the issue is checkboxes are created from another plugin which I want to enable via my plugin.

Below code, I am using

```
update_post_meta(129, 'whp_hide_on_search', 0); 
add_post_meta(129, 'whp_hide_on_search, 1);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 ways to update the meta values created by WordPress Hide Posts.

To make things easier, you can set the meta values at the time of calling `wp_insert_post`.

In your case, it will be

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'    => 'your_post_type',
    'post_status'  => 'publish',
    'content'      => 'your_content',
    'meta_input'   => array(
        '_whp_hide_on_frontpage' => true
    )
    ...
);
```

And get the post ID:

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post($args);
```

The second way is how you are already doing.

```
if ( ! add_post_meta( $post_id, '_whp_hide_on_frontpage', true, true ) ) { 
   update_post_meta ( $post_id, '_whp_hide_on_frontpage', true );
}
```

**Note**: You are updating the wrong meta key. There is an underscore (_) at the beginning. You can find all meta keys being used by WordPress Hide Posts plugin [here](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/whp-hide-posts/trunk/classes/admin/WHP_Post_Hide_Metabox.php#L109).

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I was missing the correct keys.